# Entity Framework 6 CodeFirst with Oracle and MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, oracle11g, entity-framework-6

I'm trying use CodeFirst and Entity Framework 6 because I need it to use MVC 5. I have existing database Schema on MySQL and Oracle, both with the same schema (same tables, fields, restrictions ...)

I have installed Entity Framework 6.1.3 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 to generate the Code First from Database. And I have also added MySQL.Data.Entities from Nugget.

When I'm using the wizard to generate the Codefirst from Database after selecting the connection I'm getting the following error (translated from Spanish)

> Your project is referencing to the last version of EntityFramework.
>   But Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version
>   cannot be found. If you have already installed a compatible provider
>   be sure to compile the project before doing this action. In other case
>   exit from the wizard, install a compatible provider and compile the
>   project before doing this action.

I want to do it with code first because i think this is better for working with two different providers (Oracle and MySQL). The solution have to run on both Oracle and MySQL depending on the scenario by changing the the connectionString.

The Server versions are MySQL 5.6.19 and Oracle 11g.

Comment: Have you tried asking nuget to update all packages? they might be versions that don't play well together. I have used the "update package" command with success in the past.

Comment: I have try this but I'm having the same error

Answer (score 0):

Viewing that the wizard of Visual Studio is not working I'm staring to do the process manually and I want to show it to help others with the same problem.

I have added MySQL.Entities.EF6 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess from nugget and them I have used the update-package command in nugget.

In App.config I have to add the DBProvider factories.

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=***" />
  <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
  <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=***" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

And In Entityframework section of App.config you have to add also the providers.

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" />
</providers>
```

Of course you need also de connection strings of your Database.

Them you have to implement your context like this. For Oracle you have to specify the Schema Name. For me it doesn't work without it. In the Context you have to add one DBSet Property for each Entity you have.

```
namespace EFCodeFirst.DataModel
{
    public partial class Entities : DbContext
    {
        //EntitiesOracle -> Name of the connection String
        public Entities()
            : base("name=EntitiesOracle")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //For Oracle is neccesary
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("SCHEMA_NAME");
        }

        public DbSet<T_TABLE> T_TABLE { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The last thing you have to do is create you entity T_TABLE. You can Decorate the properties of the Entity with DataAnnotations. In my case I decided to use the Entities created with Visual Studio using Database First wizard and them I have copied all to modify them with DataAnnotations, saving me create entities with their property.

```
public partial class T_TABLE
{    
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(45)]
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

Hoping this helps you if you have the same problem as me. This way is too manually but it is working well for me.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the [MySql Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net). The same for Oracle, you need to install the [Oracle Data Provider for .Net (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html). Make sure you are downloading the ODAC with Tools for your specific Visual Studio version.

Comment: I have MySQL Connector Net 6.9.6, MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.3 and MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.3 installed.

Comment: I have installed MySQL connector/Net 6.9.7 and the ODAC that you have put here and I'm also having problems with the wizard.
Installation of ODAC has failed in the transaction Manager component "Fail at Oracle Services in Microsoft Transaction Server"
Also after installing the ODAC I have this message in Visual Studio when adding a database connection "An unexpected error ocurred in the ODP Manager Provider for .NET. Please contact the provider vendor to resolve this problem.

Comment: I have try to code the clases manually without using wizards and coding manually the Database Context and it's working well with Oracle and MySQL adding the needed providers available in Nugget. So CodeFirst at the moment is working with EF6 with Oracle and MySQL. The wizards of Visual Studio are not working.

Comment: Installing MySql Connector/Net changed nothing. I still cannot connect to MySql to create an EntityFramework Model code-first-from-existing-database. MySql does not exist in any of the dropdowns.